# How to move existing shortcut icons to folder via GPO?

Tags: group-policy, shortcut

Currently, we have a set of shortcut icons that every single person has on their desktop (these icons are put on their desktop via GPO to begin wi/).  What I want to do is instead, create a folder on everyone's desktop & have all those shortcut icon's moved into that folder (so I'm guessing a move will have to be required)?  I've followed the following & was able to successfully create the folder on the desktop:

https://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/03/Create-a-Folder-on-Desktop-through-Group-Policy.html

However, I'm having problems now placing the shortcuts into the folder.  I'm not sure if I have to create another GPO or edit the existing ones (creating the shortcut GPO or creating the folder GPO).

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct Group Policy settings for moving these files. You need to remove the existing files and then create new ones inside the folder. In some cases you could use a script for moving all `.lnk` files in a folder to a subfolder. However, your current GPO would recreate them, making this approach unsuitable.